# Template for referencing classes themselves rather than a class that uses templates

Tags: c++

So I have a little unusual situation, that my experience with templates and tutorials doesn't seem to cover.

I am writing an program that automatically signs messages for another program that is incapable but has a limited API. There is a configuration file that contains a string telling my program what hash to use to sign a message.
This string is stored in a signatureAlgorithm object which stores a digest, the size the digest should be, and offers a few options for the encoding of the digest.
I am using the Crypto++ library for the hashing functions.
Right now I have a large set of if/else if statements and three commands in each one depending on what the string says the algorithm should be, as shown below:

```
void signatureAlgorithm::createDigest(string input)
{
bool digestFail = false;

if (_algorithm == "md5")
{
    //byte digest[ CryptoPP::MD5::DIGESTSIZE ];
    _digestSize = (CryptoPP::MD5::DIGESTSIZE);
    _digest = new byte[ _digestSize ];
    CryptoPP::MD5().CalculateDigest( _digest, (byte*) input.c_str(), input.length() );
}

.....

else if (_algorithm == "sha256")
{
    _digestSize = (CryptoPP::SHA256::DIGESTSIZE);
    _digest = new byte[ _digestSize ];
    CryptoPP::SHA256().CalculateDigest( _digest, (byte*) input.c_str(), input.length() );
}
else if (_algorithm == "sha512")
{
    _digestSize = (CryptoPP::SHA512::DIGESTSIZE);
    _digest = new byte[ _digestSize ];
    CryptoPP::SHA512().CalculateDigest( _digest, (byte*) input.c_str(), input.length() );
}
else
    digestFail = true;

if (!digestFail)
    _ready = true;
else
    _ready = false;
}
```

_digestSize stores the digest size in the object, as _digest does for the bytes of the digest (bytes are typedef const unsigned char*), and _ready is used in other functions to determine of the value has been digested before giving it to a calling program, or instead returning an error to the program.

I eventually plan to switch to a map to make things more efficient and tidier, however before I do I have to find a way to make the setting of _digestSize and the calling of CreateDigest() more generic. I am trying to avoid modifying the library as I want to maintain the FIPS status of Crypto++ in compiled form in the final release, but for now I'm just testing using the source if that makes a difference.

I thought about templates, with the inner section of each if statement just setting the value, but I can't find an example of the template being used in such a fashion. I find them for making classes where there are other functions, but in this case I just need to be able to make a generic class that simply points to another class if I am thinking right here.

pseudo-code for what I'm trying to do:

```
class tempClass {};

if (_algorithm == "md5")
{
  tempClass = CryptoPP::MD5
}
......
else
  digestFail = true;

_digestSize = (tempClass::DIGESTSIZE);
_digest = new byte[_digestSize];
tempClass().CalculateDigest( _digest, (byte*) input.c_str(), input.length() );
```

-Jimmy

EDIT: While in the comments I stated that inheritance wouldn't work because of the forking in the class tree, it turns out that the documentation I've been using is for the most recent version. The version I'm using for testing and the FIPS version are older, from before functions like MD5 etc were split out into a separate "weak" structure.

EDIT 2: However, I'm still curious as to if there were a way to go about this even if the classes were forked and didn't inherit CalculateDigest from the same place.

EDIT 3: John Bandela answered the question, but I just had to change what he gave me a little bit. Changes are in the comments for the answer. Thanks all!

Comment: not too sure about the crpyto++ library, but since different crpyto classes implement the same `CalculateDigewst`. Any chance that they inherit from a common parent class and `CalculateDigewst` is a virtual function? If so, you can just get a pointer to the parent class and do the job.

Comment: You are looking for concepts called *inheritance*, *virtual functions* and (optionally) *class factory*.

Comment: some of them inherit a virtual function from a higher class, but some like MD2 are at a higher level forked. The top level doesn't seem to have CalculateDigest, but right below are classes for MD2 and similar, then others like MD5 and SHA are within sub-classes inherited farther below. I thought about straight inheritance, but since they are on multiple branches and I don't want to modify Crypto++ I was wondering if there is another way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break out the code into a template function like this

// Assuming _digest and _digest size are class members;

```
template<class Digest>
byte* doDigest(string input, int& digestSize){
        int digestSize = (Digest::DIGESTSIZE);
        byte* digest = new byte[ digestSize ];
        Digest().CalculateDigest( digest, (byte*) input.c_str(), input.length() );
        return digest;
 }
```

Then in your createDigest function do this

```
if (_algorithm == "md5")
{
    _digest = doDigest<CryptoPP::MD5>(input,_digestSize);
}

else if (_algorithm == "sha256")
{
    _digest = doDigest<CryptoPP::SHA256>(input,_digestSize);
}
...
```

Off topic, but you may want to consider using a vector instead of byte*

Comment: Seems like it would work, but something's off. you have `int digestSize = (CryptoPP::MD5::DIGESTSIZE);` which has to be different for each hash, and _digestSize is calculated when the _algorithm is checked. I'm assuming I can just make another template function for `DIGEST::DIGESTSIZE`? EDIT: also, the byte* is required by Crypto++. I cannot edit the library else it loses FIPS certification

Comment: This worked given the tweak I mentioned. I also just set doDigest as void and had it set the actual private class members, and listed this as a private function. and to clarify, I think I know what you were trying to suggest with the vector. I am not storing multiple hashes, instead Crypto++ works with an array of bytes for each digest (const unsigned char*). The reason this is setup as if I can is that the program allows daisy chaining hash functions at a higher level, which some signature systems do.

Comment: Fixed it. Replace that with Digest::DIGESTSIZE. In regards to vector instead of byte* use vector&lt;byte&gt;

Comment: I don't think the suggestion about avoiding byte* was regarding multiple digests.  It's just generally better to avoid explicitly calling new especially when you are returning the result.  What if an exception is thrown and you haven't called delete[] yet? Or more likely, you just forget to call delete.  You can achieve the same thing with std::vector<byte> digest(Digest::DIGESTSIZE); Then pass &digest[0] where byte* is expected.  Now you can just return the vector and it will be cleaned up in the event of an exception.

Comment: but the createDigest function does not return a result. _digest is a class member, and the class destructor deletes it when the class goes out. It is desired to keep it until the program closes the configuration in case the caller needs to check it again, such as in cases where traffic is two way or needs to be verified after another use) And I modified John's doDigest to be void as well, just storing in the class member variable. EDIT: I could technically make the class member the vector and still do that, but I think it's just making things more complicated. The overhead for vectors is lower

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this but with more template metaprogramming

for full runnable example see

https://gist.github.com/4164700

```
template<class Digest, class... T>
struct DigestMatcher{
    template<class U, class ... V>
    static byte* doDigest(std::string input, int& digestSize,std::string algorithm,U firstalgorithm, U nextalgorithm, V... algorithms){
    if(algorithm==firstalgorithm){
        return doDigest(input,digestSize);
    }
    else{
        return DigestMatcher<T...>::doDigest(input,digestSize,algorithm,nextalgorithm,algorithms...);

    }
}

template<class U>
static byte* doDigest(std::string input, int& digestSize,std::string algorithm, U firstalgorithm){
    if(algorithm==firstalgorithm){
        return doDigest(input,digestSize);
    }
    else{
        std::cout << algorithm << " invalid" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
}

static byte* doDigest(std::string input, int& digestSize){

        // Cout for debug purposes
        std::cout << "using " << typeid(Digest).name() << std::endl;
        digestSize = Digest::DIGESTSIZE;
        byte* digest = new byte[ digestSize ];
        Digest().CalculateDigest( digest, (byte*) input.c_str(), input.length() );
        return digest;
}

};
```

Then for your calling code

```
void signatureAlgorithm::createDigest(std::string input)
{
    _digest = DigestMatcher<MD5,SHA256,SHA512>::doDigest(input,_digestSize,_algorithm,"md5","sha256","sha512");
    if(_digest)
        _ready = true;
    else
    _ready = false;
}
```